# Use array.pop() twice in a row to get second last element

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var path = document.location.pathName;
example.com/store/order/cats
```

Sometimes it might be:

```
example.com/store/order/cats/
```

Note the slash at the end.

I'd like a function to return cats in either case. If there is no trailing slash I go:

```
function() {
    return path.split('/').pop();
}
```

But if there is a trailing slash, I need to `pop()` twice. I tried this:

```
function() {
        return path.split('/').pop().pop();
    }
```

Which threw an error.

So the array arising from split('/') can be either:

```
["", "store", "order", "cats", ""] // trailing slash
```

or

```
["", "store", "order", "cats"] // no trailing slash
```

How can I return cats in either eventuality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first remove the last trailing `/` from the string and then use `pop` on the resulting string.

```
var path = document.location.pathName.replace(/\/$/, '');

var pathName = path.split('/').pop();
```

The regex `\/$` will match the trailing `/` from the string. The `/` need to escape by preceding with `\`.

You can also use string methods as follow:

```
if (path.charAt(path.length - 1) === '/') {
    path = path.substr(0, path.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just want to understand the regex here. .replace(/\/$/, '') So it will match the trailing slash if it's there, but what's it doing if there is no trailing slash? Won't it remove the "s" in cats? (I tested and it looks like this does not happen, so that's good. But how does the regex do this?)

Comment: I think I get it now. Replace only replaces if it finds the match /$. Thanks again!

Comment: @DougFirr No, it'll only remove the trailing slash if it is there, if there is no trailing slash it will not do anything

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you could try removing the last character if it is a slash, and then using the first method.

```
function getLastWordInPathName() {
  var path = document.location.pathName.replace(/\/$/, '');
  return path.split('/').pop();
}
```

However, your question was asking why you can't call `pop()` twice.

The first time you call `pop()`, the value of the last element in the array is returned. When you call `pop()` again, this function is applied to the result of the previous function - so you are calling `pop()` on the string `'/'`, and not on your array.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed many ways to skin a cat. These assume you want one liners rather than something more defensive and that performs well.

If you always want the second from last

```
[1,2,3,4,5].slice(-2).shift()
4
```

This will likely perform very slightly better:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].slice(-2, -1)[0]
4
```

To extract all non-empty delimited items:

```
'/a/b//c/d/'.match(/[^\/]+/g)
[a, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by far the simplest approach:

```
// Couldn't resist :)
function getCats( location ) {
    if ( location.charAt( location.length-1 ) == "/" ) {
        location = location.slice(0, -1)
    }

    return location.split("/").pop()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.pop() returns the last element, not the original Array. So the second pop() is called on the last element. If it does not have pop method, you get an error...

To get the second path element from the end use `path.replace(/.*\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$/,'$1')`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zarjay/mbggs/ `pop` is **a lot** more efficient than `RegExp`

Have a look at this bit of code now:

```
function( ) {
  var paths = path.split( "/" ),
      cats = paths.pop( );

  if( !cats ) {
    cats = paths.pop( );
  }

  return cats;
}
```

You see after you `pop` paths the first time, you remove the last element of the array

Now if you find that that element is empty, you just `pop` again and you get the element you want

Your performance is going to be a lot better and if you ever use this in a loop with thousands of iterations you'll get a performance boost in the order of seconds

And that's neat

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate and throw away empty path elements at the end:

```
function pathTail(path) {
  for (var split = path.split("/"), tail = split.pop(); !tail; tail = split.pop());
  return tail;
}
```

Or you can use a regular expression:

```
function pathTail(path) {
  return path.replace(/^.*\/([^/]+)\/*$/, "$1");
}
```